# Extension missing for images rendered via readfile() function on downloading using php

Tags: php, file-io, content-type

The extensions are missing for images downloaded from a image which is rendered using `readfile` function.

The **getphoto** function code looks like this:

```
    <?php

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
    header('Cache-Control:public, max-age=864000');
    header('Content-Type:image/jpg');
    header('Expires: access plus 30 days');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($filePath);
    ?>

    <img src="http://localhost/prjt/getphoto/ZmLj" />
```

Comment: So... The extensions are missing

Comment: yes it is getting downloaded as zmLj file with image showing in image viewer.... how can i add type when user tries to download image like zmLj.jpg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `content-disposition` header:

```
   header('Content-Disposition: attachement; ' .
               ' filename="yourimage.suf"; size="'2311"');
```

this will tell the browser to open a download dialog with the given filename.

Next, you won't render an html tag after streaming the data of the image to the client. 
And, after putting the headers in the buffer, you shouldn't erase them with `ob_clean`.
Full code:

```
<?php

    ob_clean();

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
    header('Cache-Control:public, max-age=864000');
    header('Content-Type:image/jpg');
    header('Expires: access plus 30 days');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; ' .
                   ' filename="yourimage.suf"; size="'2311"');

    readfile($filePath);

?>
// EOF !!
```